# Over writing to 2 files at the same time in java

Tags: java, file

I would like to write to 2 different txt files at the same time with the same data but currently i can over-write one file but the other, help guys??

```
            if (choice.charAt(0) == 'y' || choice.charAt(0) == 'Y'){
                credits = 10;
                System.out.println("Redeemed! Congratulations! $1.00 worth of credits have been added to your account.");
                int finalpoints = points - credits;
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Transaction.history",true);
                    fw.write(firstname + ";" + Integer.toString(finalpoints) + ";" + "$1.00" + ";" + dateToPrintToFile + "\r\n");
                    fw.close();

                }catch (IOException ee){
                    System.out.println("Input file not found!");
                }
                //int finalpoints1 = points - credits;
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Points" , true);
                    fw.write(firstname + ";" + Integer.toString(point -credits));
                    fw.close();
                }catch (IOException ee){
                    System.out.println("Input file not found!");
                }

            }
```

Comment: and what happens when you run it?

Comment: can you be specific to the problem you are facing @EljayLee?

Comment: it only overwrites to one of the files ( Transaction.history ) and not the other ( Points ) @johnnyuag

Comment: what do you mean overwrite? your code appends to the files, not overwrites them.

Comment: Just as an experiment, try swapping round the two blocks of code; so you can find out whether it's some kind of logic in the order you're writing to the files, or some intrinsic property of the files themselves.

Comment: @EljayLee, the data you are trying to write currently is not same as per above code. Also this data is just appending to the files not overwriting it.